# Speech to text in c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice, speech-to-text

I have a c# program that lets me use my microphone and when I speak, it does commands and will talk back. For example, when I say "What's the weather tomorrow?" It will reply with tomorrows weather.

The only problem is, I have to type out every phrase I want to say and have it pre-recorded. So if I want to ask for the weather, I HAVE to say it like i coded it, no variations. I am wondering if there is code to change this?

I want to be able to say "Whats the weather for tomorrow", "whats tomorrows weather" or "can you tell me tomorrows weather" and it tell me the next days weather, but i don't want to have to type in each phrase into code. I seen something out there about e.Result.Alternates, is that what I need to use?

Comment: Probably you want to give a question a more meaningful title. That will help you to get a good answer. In particular it's not clear if you want to recognize just weather commands or any freeform text. For the latter case there is a free form dictation grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done without involving linguistic resources. Let me explain what I mean by this.

As you may have noticed, your C# program only recognizes pre-recorded phrases and only if you say the exact same words. (As an aside node, this is quite an achievement in itself, because you can hardly say a sentence twice without altering it a bit. Small changes, that is, e.g. in sound frequency or lengths, might not be relevant to your colleagues, but they matter to your program).

Therefore, you need to incorporate a kind of linguistic resource in your program. In other words, make it "understand" facts about human language. Two suggestions with increasing complexity below. All apporaches assume that your tool is capable of tokenizing an audio input stream in a sensible way, i.e. extract words from it.

**Pattern matching**

To avoid hard-coding the sentences like

```
Tell me about the weather.
What's the weather tomorrow?
Weather report!
```

you can instead define a pattern that matches any of those sentences:

```
if a sentence contains "weather", then output a weather report
```

This can be further refined in manifold ways, e.g. :

```
if a sentence contains "weather" and "tomorrow", output tomorrow's forecast.
if a sentence contains "weather" and "Bristol", output a forecast for Bristol
```

This kind of knowledge must be put into your program explicitly, for instance in the form of a dictionary or lookup table.

**Measuring Similarity**

If you plan to spend more time on this, you could implement a means for finding the similarity between input sentences. There are many approaches to this as well, but a prominent one is a *bag of words*, represented as a vector.

In this model, each sentence is represented as a vector, each word in it present as a dimension of the vector. For example, the sentence "I hate green apples" could be represented as

```
I = 1
hate = 1
green = 1
apples = 1
red = 0
you = 0
```

Note that the words that do not occur in this particular sentence, but in other phrases the program is likely to encounter, also represent dimensions (for example the `red = 0`).

The big advantage of this approach is that the similarity of vectors can be easily computed, no matter how multi-dimensional they are. There are several techniques that estimate similarity, one of them is *cosine similarity* (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

---

On a more general note, there are many other considerations to be made of course.

For example, some words might be utterly irrelevant to the message you want to convey, as in the following sentence:

```
I want you to output a weather report.
```

Here, at least "I", "you" "to" and "a" could be done away with without damaging the basic semantics of the sentence. Such words are called *stop words* and are discarded early in many tools that perform speech-to-text analysis.

Also note that we started out assuming that your program reliably identifies sound input. In reality, no tool is capable of infallibly identifying speech.

Humans tend to forget that sound actually exists without cues as to where word or sentence boundaries are. This makes so-called *disambiguation* of input a gargantuan task that is easily underestimated - and **ambiguity** one of the hardest problems of computational linguistics in general.

Answer (score 1):

For that, the code won't be able to judge that! You need to split the command in text array! Such as

1. Tomorrow
2. Weather
3. What

This way, you will compare it with the text that is present in your computer! Lets say, with the command (what) with type (weather) and with the time (tomorrow).

It is better to read and understand each word, then guess it will work as Google! Google uses the same, they break down the string and compare it.

Comment: I agree with this.  The computer doesn't know what you mean, it just 'ranks' your words and does its best to figure out what you want.  Ex. "What is the weather tomorrow?" and "What if I am feeling under the weather tomorrow?" will probably return similar results.